# Kubeam failed | service is down

Tags: kubernetes, centos

I try to join worker node to k8s kluser.

```
sudo kubeadm join 10.2.67.201:6443 --token  x   --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha2566 x
```

But i get error on this stage:

```
curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz'
```

failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp

Error:

```
Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)
```

I see that kubelet service is down:

```
journalctl -xeu kubelet
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit kubelet.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 22 15:49:00 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
-- Subject: Unit kubelet.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit kubelet.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 22 15:49:00 s001as-ceph-node-03 kubelet[286703]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag.
Nov 22 15:49:00 s001as-ceph-node-03 kubelet[286703]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag.
Nov 22 15:49:00 s001as-ceph-node-03 kubelet[286703]: F1122 15:49:00.224350  286703 server.go:251] unable to load client CA file /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt: open /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.cr
Nov 22 15:49:00 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Nov 22 15:49:00 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Nov 22 15:49:00 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
-- Subject: Unit kubelet.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit kubelet.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
-- Subject: Unit kubelet.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit kubelet.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 kubelet[286717]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag.
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 kubelet[286717]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag.
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 kubelet[286717]: F1122 15:49:10.476478  286717 server.go:251] unable to load client CA file /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt: open /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.cr
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Nov 22 15:49:10 s001as-ceph-node-03 systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
```

Comment: Could you please post your kubeadm, kubelet and kubectl version? also the accompanying config file which you used with `kubeadm init`

Comment: Is it cloud virtual machine or bare metal one? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

Just copy /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt into /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt